# PHP automatically change variable date +1 day

Tags: php

I am writing a email application which has a graphical statistic page, The graph shows how many e-mails a user has send per day, I can get the data for the graph correctly for each day only if I hard code it, but I would like to know how to make a automatic mechanism to.

this is a query I use to get data from database:

Query:

```
 $today = "SELECT COUNT(tbl_template_log.user_id) FROM tbl_template_log ";
            $today .= "WHERE tbl_template_log.user_id='$id'";
            //$today .= " AND tbl_template_log.send_date > '2014-05-21' ";
            //$today .= "AND tbl_template_log.send_date < '2014-05-21'";
```

But I would like to have variables instead of the dates like $start and $finish that are readjusted for everyday day, So user can se an actual daily data without me manually changing the data....?

my PHP class:

```
class statsToday{

function con()
{
    require_once('connect.php');
    $DB = new dbConnect();
    return $DB->connect();
    }

    public $start;
    public $finish;

    public function getStats($user){

            $user = "SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE ott_email='$user'";
            $query = mysqli_query($this->con(), $user);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if($count == 1){

             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                 $id = $row['user_id'];
             }

            $today = "SELECT COUNT(tbl_template_log.user_id) FROM tbl_template_log ";
            $today .= "WHERE tbl_template_log.user_id='$id'";
            //$today .= " AND tbl_template_log.send_date > '$start' ";
            //$today .= "AND tbl_template_log.send_date < '$finihs''";
            $query_today = mysqli_query($this->con(), $today);
            $today = mysqli_fetch_row($query_today);

            echo $today[0];
        }

    }
}
```

Could somebody suggest a solution..?

Comment: thx for your comment, well I am not a pro maybe you could suggest best way to code this...?

Comment: To have a script run automatically, you can use CRON.

Comment: ye but thats server functionality I wont some help with making a php mechanism to do this.

Comment: Automatic mechanisms don't happen on their own, not without CRON anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want "today" you can use the built in [mysql date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function in the form of:

```
$today = "SELECT COUNT(tbl_template_log.user_id) FROM tbl_template_log ";
$today .= "WHERE tbl_template_log.user_id='$id'";
$today .= " AND DATE(send_date) = DATE(NOW())";
```

Or to do all in the last week:

```
$today = "SELECT COUNT(tbl_template_log.user_id) FROM tbl_template_log ";
$today .= "WHERE tbl_template_log.user_id='$id'";
$today .= " AND tbl_template_log.send_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week')) . "' ";
$today .= "AND tbl_template_log.send_date =< '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today')) . "'";
```

Comment: could you explain this to me lease if you don't mind...? " AND DATE(send_date) = DATE(NOW())";

Comment: That gets the date in your `send_date` field and compares it to today's date (`NOW()`). If `send_date` is the same as today's day then it's selected.

Comment: owww ok that sound perfect, what about if I would like to do the same but for a whole month...? or week...?

Comment: For that you'll have to use some PHP. I did it with `strtotime` and `date()`. See my edit. But this will only grab everything for the week or month, it won't break it out by day.

Comment: this is amazing thank you so much, for your help and understanding my question, because some plz did not, if I could I would give you a vote up as well. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another way, a little easier to use if you are indexing the database on the send_date field:

```
$today = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM tbl_template_log
  WHERE user_id='$id'
  AND send_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY";
```